# Not able to run Odoo with --workers option

Tags: python, odoo-8, python-2.x, odoo

I am trying to run Odoo8 in multiprocessing mode using `--workers` option. It runs fine without `--workers` parameter but with the `--workers` parameter it gives me error

> socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

It seems like each of the worker process is trying to bind to one port.

Here is my run configuration

```
python openerp-server --addons-path my_adons_paths --db_user my_db_user --db_password my_db_password --db-filter my_db_to_use --no-database-list --workers 2
```

Am I doing something wrong here or there is some bug in Odoo?

I have checked there is no process already running on 8069 port, also server runs fine without `--workers 2` parameter. That is with

```
python openerp-server --addons-path my_adons_paths --db_user my_db_user --db_password my_db_password --db-filter my_db_to_use --no-database-list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got the issue resolved!

Problem was from my side. For debugging (which has not been possible without this) I had `evented = False` in my `odoo/openerp/__init__.py` file.

To be more specific I had these lines commented

```
if sys.modules.get("gevent") is not None:
    evented = True
```

Which caused the issue, setting it to True again (enabling the above lines) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also have a lot of problems when I set workers greater than zero. It's very weird that you are getting the error *Address already in use* and you don't have any process running there. When I get that error, I kill all processes running on the Odoo port and then I can start Odoo again.

Just in case, try doing this before starting the Odoo server again:

```
sudo fuser -k 8069/tcp
```